# Phaser 3 disable pushing objects

Tags: phaser-framework

If I push an object, I can push it onto the texture. How can I disable pushing and the ability to push objects to prohibited areas?

```
    let map = this.make.tilemap({key: 'map'});
    let tiles = map.addTilesetImage('map', 'tiles');

    this.grass = map.createStaticLayer('Ground/Base', tiles, 0, 0);
    let obstacles = map.createStaticLayer('tree', tiles, 0, 0);
    obstacles.setCollisionByExclusion([-1]);

        let player = new Player(this, 50, 100);
        let enemy = new Enemy(this, 100, 100);

        this.player = this.physics.add.existing(player);
        this.enemy = this.physics.add.existing(enemy);

        let players = this.physics.add.group();
        players.addMultiple([
            player,
            enemy
        ]);

       this.physics.add.collider(players, obstacles);
       this.physics.add.collider(players, players, (player1, player2) => {
            player1.body.setVelocity(0);
            player2.body.setVelocity(0);
        });
```

Player and Enemy extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite; setImmovable() - changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new using Phaser but this is what i found reading the github:

**If you're using Phaser v3.24.1 or less:**

You can check [SeparateX](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/v3.24.1/src/physics/arcade/SeparateX.js) that is the function that process what you refer to as Push, [here](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/v3.24.1/src/physics/arcade/SeparateX.js#L45) is where you get moved like pushed and [here](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/v3.24.1/src/physics/arcade/SeparateX.js#L55) is where you get bounced, look how `body1.velocity.x = avg + nv1 * body1.bounce.x` multiply occurs only for nv1 and that's why don't matter if you set bounce to 0, you will still get bounced. There also exists [SeparateY](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/v3.24.1/src/physics/arcade/SeparateY.js).

Maybe you can take advantage of `Body#customSeparateX` and `Body#customSeparateY`, [example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/physics/arcade/custom-separate). Notice that in that example you need to build your own Push Process but this occurs after object1 move into object2.

**Phaser v3.50.0-beta.7:**

Recently in this [commit](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/commit/69b8458bb8bef39a9502c1828c43379c8562a352) added new pushable component, so you can use that Phaser version or wait for the official release. I didn't test it but i'm assuming that it works very well. If you want to know where the Push Process occurs now you can check [ProcessX](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/c8a99f00f21dfbe59b59978188c04d895b40f328/src/physics/arcade/ProcessX.js#L180) and [ProcessY](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/master/src/physics/arcade/ProcessY.js#L180).

I hope it helped you.